# software-center diplays info on apps that i have not installed

Tags: 12.04, software-center, malware

While installing a deb file using software-centre the following info is printed on the terminal

```
2015-03-07 14:05:22,035 - softwarecenter.db.update - INFO - skipping region restricted app: 'Just Play MP3' (not whitelisted)
2015-03-07 14:05:22,357 - softwarecenter.db.update - INFO - skipping region restricted app: 'Source Code Analyzer' (not whitelisted)
2015-03-07 14:05:22,683 - softwarecenter.db.update - INFO - skipping region restricted app: 'Flaggame' (not whitelisted)
2015-03-07 14:05:22,877 - softwarecenter.db.update - INFO - skipping region restricted app: 'Comentarios Web' (not whitelisted)
2015-03-07 14:05:23,270 - softwarecenter.db.update - INFO - skipping region restricted app: '蚂蚁浏览器' (not whitelisted)
```

I have never installed any chinese apps. Is it a malware?

Comment: I've made it an answer instead, accept it if you think that's good enough :/

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just updating the software centre database of apps that you COULD install and it's saying that, for whatever reason, those apps aren't meant to be for the region which you live in. I imagine because you don't want a Chinese app if you're English (or whatever)!

Source: Reading what it says and guessing.